# Using mvc5 Controller.Execute with attribute routing feature is causing exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC5 with the routing attribute decoration on my controller actions. I would like to use the Controller.Execute command inside the Application_Error function to transfer the call to mvc but i'm getting the exception **"A public action method 'HttpError404' was not found on controller 'ErrorsController'."**.

If i remove the RouteAttribute decoration, everything is working but i do need the RouteAttribute decoration. Why is it happening and how can i solve this problem considering that i don't want to use the `HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest` trick?

### ErrorsController

```
[RoutePrefix("Errors")]
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    [Route("HttpError404")]
    public ActionResult HttpError404()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

### Application_Error

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "errors");
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "HttpError404");

    var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), routeData);
    var controllerFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
    var controller = controllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, "errors");

    try
    {
        controller.Execute(requestContext);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        //A public action method 'HttpError404' was not found on controller 'ErrorsController'.           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue and got this error output log:

> System.Web.HttpException was caught
>
> HResult=-2147467259 (0x80004005)
>
> Message=A public action method 'HttpError404' was not found on controller
> '[ApplicationName].Controllers.ErrorsController'.
>
> Source=System.Web.Mvc
>
> ErrorCode=-2147467259
>
> WebEventCode=0
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
> requestContext)
>
> at [ApplicationName].MvcApplication.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> [ProjectPath]\[ApplicationName]\[ApplicationName]\Global.asax.cs:line XX

By seeing exception details above, the exception originated from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction` method which by default looks like this (taken from [aspnetwebstack reference](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs)):

```
protected virtual void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
{
    // If this is a direct route we might not yet have an action name
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName))
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, MvcResources.Controller_UnknownAction_NoActionName, GetType().FullName));
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, MvcResources.Controller_UnknownAction, actionName, GetType().FullName));
    }
}
```

As a workaround, try overriding that method by returning view from corresponding action method (using same name as action method name) as given in example below:

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    // put error action methods here

    protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
    {
        // returns view from given action name
        // better to use try-catch block just in case the view name is not exist
        this.View(actionName).ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** Use if-condition or `switch...case` block if you have different view names against action method names.

**Note 2:** It is possible that standard routing messed up while `RouteAttribute` is enabled and calling `HandleUnknownAction` by unknown reason, I recommend to remove attribute routing if corresponding action method called with `IController.Execute`.

References:

[MVC 5 Attribute Routing not Working with Controller Execute](https://forums.asp.net/t/1957536.aspx?MVC%205%20Attribute%20Routing%20not%20Working%20with%20Controller%20Execute%20What%20is%20the%20alternative%20)

[Handling Unknown Actions in ASP.NET MVC](http://dotnet-helpers.com/mvc/use-views-without-action-using-mvchandleunknownaction-mvc/)